# Добавить элемент в массив, после определенного номера JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Как можно добавить элемент в массив, после определенного номера.
Например у меня есть массив - `readyArray = [45, 12, 54, 23]`
Как можно добавить, например 60, после 12. Как это сделать? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ой. А "после определенного номера" - это про номер элемента, или конкретне значениие  12 ?)

Comment: Номер элемента)

Comment: `splice()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого есть функция [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

> `array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])`
>
> **start**
>
> Индекс, по которому начинает изменять массив. Если больше длины
>   массива, реальный индекс будет установлен на длину массива. Если
>   отрицателен, указывает индекс элемента с конца.
>
> **deleteCount**
>
> Целое число, показывающее количество старых удаляемых из массива
>   элементов. Если deleteCount равен 0, элементы не удаляются. В этом
>   случае вы должны указать как минимум один новый элемент. Если
>   deleteCount больше количества элементов, оставшихся в массиве, начиная
>   с индекса start, то будут удалены все элементы до конца массива.
>
> **itemN**
>
> Необязательные параметры. Добавляемые к массиву элементы. Если вы не
>   укажете никакого элемента, splice() просто удалит элементы из массива.

```js
const readyArray = [45, 12, 54, 23];
readyArray.splice(2, 0, 60);
console.log(readyArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addNumToArray(inputNum, pointerNum, arr) {
  const index = arr.findIndex(el => el === pointerNum);

  return index !== -1 ? [
    ...arr.slice(0, index + 1),
    inputNum,
    ...arr.slice(index + 1)
  ] : arr;
}

console.log(addNumToArray(60, 12, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 18, 23, 46]))
```